# I don't know how to fix. It will reflect in my all applications where I use the react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-fullstack

| [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCRpo.jpg) | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |  |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |  |

I want to clear this problem but I can't still now. Last 4 days I'll searching for the result but none of it was working. This problem is reflect in my all react application with no relation.

Comment: what is the issue can you explain in details?